# Ambitions To/For

Tags: parsing

I have a question about a preposition used with the noun "*ambition*" [here](http://www.reuters.com/article/2014/11/05/us-usa-elections-idUSKBN0IO0C620141105):

> The Republican takeover will force Obama to scale back his ***ambitions to*** either executive actions that do not require legislative approval, or items that might gain bipartisan support, such as trade agreements and tax reform.

When one have ambitions, it is usually "*ambitions* ***for***" something, not "*ambitions* ***to***" something.  So, is the example passage wrong?

Comment: Hint: Focus on the words **scale back**

Answer (score 2):

Usually it is "ambitions for", but that is when the following phrases describe something that you want to do.

In this case, the meaning is different. He's "scaling back his ambitions". His ambitions are being **changed** *to* specific executive actions or items.

So it's not describing his ambitions per se. It's more describing what they're being changed to.

Comment: +1 Also consider that "The Republican takeover will force Obama to scale back his ambitions" is a complete sentence. "to either" is the following phrase; the phrase is not "ambitions to."

Answer (score 0):

@Manish has laid out the right clue, and the answer by @Millie Smith points in the right direction, but I think the point needs to be made clearer. I hope I have come closer to the answer.

The preposition "to" is the preposition to the noun phrase which follows it and together with it forms a *prepositional phrase*, that functions as an indirect object (while "ambitions" is the direct object of the verb):

> What does Obama have to scale back his *ambitions to*?
>   His *ambitions* ... are scaled back *to* either etc. etc.

The vicinity of "ambitions" and "to" can produce the illusional effect that both words form one phrase.

"To" is not used as a preposition of purpose that relates to and modifies the noun "ambitions". Rather, it modifies the phrasal verb "scale".
Hence it is an *adverbial prepositional phrase*. ([Source](http://www.cws.illinois.edu/workshop/writers/prepphrases/))